# error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 -Python3.7 MacOs Catalina

Tags: macos, gcc, macos-catalina

I was trying to install superset by pip and the error occurs.

I've already tried

sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /

but I found there are no such packages on macOS Catalina.

Comment: Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

That package does not exist on Catalina.
After installing Xcode Beta on Catalina beta, the headers are available on:

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/

You may have to adjust your library path