# error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 MacOs Catalina

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, macos, macos-catalina

When I create a new virtual env I am facing build issues. I figured after reading a couple of threads that it has to do with gcc issue with new upgrade.

I referred to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57230660/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-python3-7-macos-catalina).

I tried to install using the `sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -target /` based on the above thread and other suggestions but it still doesn't seem to work

Stacktrace

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:326:9: error: no member named 'isless' in the global namespace
using ::isless;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:327:9: error: no member named 'islessequal' in the global namespace
using ::islessequal;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:328:9: error: no member named 'islessgreater' in the global namespace
using ::islessgreater;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:329:9: error: no member named 'isunordered' in the global namespace
using ::isunordered;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:330:9: error: no member named 'isunordered' in the global namespace
using ::isunordered;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:641:26: error: use of undeclared identifier 'numeric_limits'
    bool _FloatBigger = (numeric_limits<_FloatT>::digits > numeric_limits<_IntT>::digits),
                         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:641:41: error: '_FloatT' does not refer to a value
    bool _FloatBigger = (numeric_limits<_FloatT>::digits > numeric_limits<_IntT>::digits),
                                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:640:30: note: declared here
template <class _IntT, class _FloatT,
                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:641:51: error: no member named 'digits' in the global namespace
    bool _FloatBigger = (numeric_limits<_FloatT>::digits > numeric_limits<_IntT>::digits),
                                                ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:641:60: error: use of undeclared identifier 'numeric_limits'
    bool _FloatBigger = (numeric_limits<_FloatT>::digits > numeric_limits<_IntT>::digits),
                                                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:641:75: error: '_IntT' does not refer to a value
    bool _FloatBigger = (numeric_limits<_FloatT>::digits > numeric_limits<_IntT>::digits),
                                                                          ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:640:17: note: declared here
template <class _IntT, class _FloatT,
                ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:641:83: error: no member named 'digits' in the global namespace
    bool _FloatBigger = (numeric_limits<_FloatT>::digits > numeric_limits<_IntT>::digits),
                                                                                ~~^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
213 warnings and 20 errors generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for thinc
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/akshay.uppalimanage.com/anaconda3/envs/metis-env2/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/hw/wsfzlw096hz0h9ndrhdvqf600000gq/T/pip-install-3zketryo/thinc/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/hw/wsfzlw096hz0h9ndrhdvqf600000gq/T/pip-install-3zketryo/thinc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/hw/wsfzlw096hz0h9ndrhdvqf600000gq/T/pip-record-qd2uy_lm/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
       cwd: /private/var/folders/hw/wsfzlw096hz0h9ndrhdvqf600000gq/T/pip-install-3zketryo/thinc/
  Complete output (10 lines):
  Warning: The nvcc binary could not be located in your $PATH. For GPU capability, either add it to your path, or set $CUDA_HOME
  running install
  running build
  running build_py
  running build_ext
  building 'thinc.linalg' extension
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/akshay.uppalimanage.com/anaconda3/envs/metis-env2/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/akshay.uppalimanage.com/anaconda3/envs/metis-env2/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/akshay.uppalimanage.com/anaconda3/envs/metis-env2/include/python3.6m -I/private/var/folders/hw/wsfzlw096hz0h9ndrhdvqf600000gq/T/pip-install-3zketryo/thinc/include -I/Users/akshay.uppalimanage.com/anaconda3/envs/metis-env2/include/python3.6m -c thinc/linalg.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/thinc/linalg.o -O3 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function
  clang: error: no such file or directory: 'thinc/linalg.cpp'
  clang: error: no input files
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/akshay.uppalimanage.com/anaconda3/envs/metis-env2/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/hw/wsfzlw096hz0h9ndrhdvqf600000gq/T/pip-install-3zketryo/thinc/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/hw/wsfzlw096hz0h9ndrhdvqf600000gq/T/pip-install-3zketryo/thinc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/hw/wsfzlw096hz0h9ndrhdvqf600000gq/T/pip-record-qd2uy_lm/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.


CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

Comment: Try using `clang` as your C compiler, after installing **XCode**. AFAIK, you can get **XCode** from the AppStore.

Comment: "failed with exit status 1" happens for basically any/every error; ideally, try to ask a question that's specific to the individual failure you're seeing, making the question self-contained enough that someone knows what you're talking about without needing to follow links.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy updated the post with more content.

Comment: That's pretty clear -- the code has, well, a bunch of errors in it, so it can't be compiled. You'd need a [mcve] as a C++ question, not a Python question, for it to be topical here (as it's a C++ object your Python module uses that is failing). If not doing that, it would at least be a bit helpful to expand the content in the post all the way back to where the compiler is first starting to build the file it fails in.

Comment: Coming in mid-way through the list of errors associated with a specific file's compilation through leaves off some context -- honestly, you could have the start of the compilation of that file and the end, and leave out most of the middle, which is just a list of where additional instances of the same error occur (and not something we can usefully debug without, again, a [mcve] with the shortest possible C++ code causing that same error).

Comment: ...right now, we don't even know which program it is that's including the `cmath` library partway through its compilation, and having errors in same. (That said, I wouldn't be surprised if Mark Setchell was right, and this was caused by g++ trying to use clang headers; can't say for sure since the logs don't go back that far, though).